# Why ipaddress is not working if replaced with local host?

Tags: ip-address, snmp, net-snmp

I am working on snmp simulator.
I created .snmprec files and able to make it listen using following blog.

http://snmpsim.sourceforge.net/simulating-agents.html

so I can see

```
Listening at:
  UDP/IPv4 endpoint 127.0.0.1:1161, transport ID 1.3.6.1.6.1.1.0
  UDP/IPv6 endpoint ::1:1161, transport ID 1.3.6.1.2.1.100.1.2.0
```

Now I am sending snmp request as following and got success

snmpwalk -On -v2c -c recorded/linksys-system localhost:1161 1.3.6

But when I replace localhost with my ipaddress ( using ipconfig ipv4) it giving me following output ( no response )

```
snmpwalk -On -v2c -c recorded/linksys-system [ipaddress]:1161 1.3.6
Timeout: No Response from [ipaddress]:1161
```

Both simulator and snmp application sender are runnign on same machine.

How can I make it work on ip address?

Comment: Well, you showed in your first output that the application seems to listen only to localhost / 127.0.0.1. Ensure your application listen to your external IP (ie: `0.0.0.0` in IPv4 and `::` in IPv6) and no firewall is in the way before running `snmpwalk`.

Comment: This looks like you are having problems using an application (snmpsim). Unless your question is specifically related to programming, please use superuser.com, or serverfault.com, instead.